# Add new variable with for loop and if statements in R

Tags: r

Let's assume I have a data set with 2 variables, a and b, where all b's are a's, but not all a's are b's.

```
a<-rbind(1,1,1,1,1)
b<-rbind(0,0,0,1,1)
d<-cbind(a,b)
d
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    1    0
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1    1
```

I want to create a new third variable to condense this information into a single data frame. I attempted to do so by writing a loop for 1 in nrows, if the a variable is 1 then write a 2, and if the b variable is 1 then write a 1

```
e<- for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    if (d[,1]==1) {
        e$new[,i] <- 2
    } # end if 1
    else (d[,2]==1)
    e$new[,i]<-1
        } # end for 2

} # end for
```

I basically want the output to look as such:

```
> d
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    2
 [2,]    1    0    2
 [3,]    1    0    2
 [4,]    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1
```

I keep getting an error: Error in e$new[, i] <- 0 : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1:x : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In if (d[, 1] == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Any help debugging the script would be appreciated!

Comment: There are two problems in your code as far as I can see. Firstly,  you can not use a variable without defining it, here the `e` variable; secondly, e$new is already a list/vector whose element you should not access by `[ ,i]`, `[i]` should be enough.

Comment: `c(2,1)[d[,1] + d[,2]]` also works just using a bit of creative indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, @Psidom I just need to initialize the "e" object with " e<- NULL"?

Comment: If you want to initialize a vector, just use `e <- c()`, then use it in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make things easier, I converted your matrix into a data frame

```
a<-rbind(1,1,1,1,1)
b<-rbind(0,0,0,1,1)
d<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

This makes some operations easier (if necessary, you can always use as.matrix(data_frame) to convert it back into a matrix)

Here is the for loop that I came up with

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if((d[i,1] == 1 & d[i,2] == 0) == TRUE){
        d$V3[i] <- 2
    }else if((d[i,2] == 1) == TRUE){
        d$V3[i] <- 1
    }
}
```

What I believe it is happening is that you want to test the condition that one element is equal to one, but your operation returns a vector. Therefore, I slightly altered the condition by adding a row and a column subscript and making it boolean.

Another possibility to achieve the result you are expecting is to use a ifelse command in the following way

```
##This is just to recreate the data frame
remove(list = ls())
a<-rbind(1,1,1,1,1)
b<-rbind(0,0,0,1,1)
d<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
d$V3 <- ifelse(d$V1 == 1 & d$V2 == 0, 2,1)
```

Comment: Agree with the use of ifelse by @Harro-Cyranka, and if the OP needs to have a situation where a == 0, you could make use of nested ifelse statements:
`d$V3 <- ifelse(d$V1 ==1 & d$V2 == 0, 2, ifelse(d$V1 == 0, 0, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Harro-Cyranka and @user5042861! Much obliged!